# Unity GoogleCard Board render single eye insteed of 2 eyes

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I'm discovering the unity and google card board world, by following tutorials.

This on in particular: [tutorail](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zYE5O9LUL2WcxZShAwSQxk7dETCcptKSN-K1ihCeE2s/edit#heading=h.nj23sjpj5u97), the text version of [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rxln-dshJJk) youtube tutorial. Here is a resume of what I did:

[Resume](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYlUg.png)

My problem is when I'm launching my game on my mobile phone, I have the game on full screen, as a normal application, and I can't have the "two eyes vision" as needed for the vr.

Does someone knows where is the problem?

Comment: Hi CoJump, please provide additional information to tackle the question. E.g. which tutorial are you following, which system are you using, what is your concrete issue and where are you stuck?

Comment: Thank's for your answer, I edited my post with the link to the tutorials. I don't have any bug. It's just about the render that is like a normal application and not a vr one. I don't find how to change it